# Как с помощью кода узнать сайт находится на локальном сервере или на хостинге?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, apache, nginx

Нужно вставить google аналитику на сайт но так чтобы оно работало только на хостинге, не на локальном сервере
для этого хочу использовать `if else` какое условие использовать чтобы точно определить, что  это хостинг, не локальный сервер ?

Привязать условие к имени домена не рассматриваю, оно может изменится.

Comment: Если вы не рассматриваете домены, то в чем критерий вашей локальности? То есть, что если локальный сервер станет хостингом? Что в вашем понимании "локальный сервер", на уровне приложения, а не на уровне вашего представления о нем?

Comment: Для этого обычно используется dev/test/release конфигурационные файлы или переменные системы, которые устанавливаются на хосте.

Answer (score 6):

В файле .env есть значение **APP_ENV=** Если проект находится на локалке поставьте значение **local**, в случае если проект на хостинге поставьте значение **production**.
После чего вы сможете проверить это значение в любом месте проекта

```
  if (App::environment('production')) {
        // Ваш код
  }
```

Comment: Есть ли среди php функций возможность определить это хостинг или нет  через dns или другое?